# Inheritance with static methods/fields c++

Tags: c++, inheritance, static-methods, static-members

I have a class of `Enemy` that i want to be the base class for all enemy types and also pure abstract one. At this point, all of its members and methods should be shared by the derived classes. Especially, there is the method `loadTexture` that uses the static member `texture`.

```
    class Enemy
    {
        int hp;
        int damage;
        //
        // all other fields
        //
        static TextureClass* texture; //needs to be static because every instance
                                      //of enemy uses the same texture
    public:
        static void loadTexture()
        {
            CreateTextureFromFile("somefilepath",&texture); //needs to be static
          // because textures are loaded before any instance is crated
        }
        void draw()
        {
            DrawToScreen(&texture, ...many data members passed here...);
        }
    };

    TextureClass* Enemy::texture = nullptr;
```

Now, if i would like to make the `Enemy` abstract and create different enemy types, the obvious choice would be inheritance. So i create:

```
class EnemyA : Enemy
{
    static TextureClass* texture;
};

class EnemyB : Enemy
{
    static TextureClass* texture;
};
```

But now, how do i load the texture for each of those? I can't use `loadTexture` defined in base obviously. So the only choice besides writing the same method X times (where X is the number of enemy types) is to remove `loadTexture` from base and create a global function, right? Same goes for `draw`, i would need to redefine it for every derived, even though it would look exactly the same...

TL;DR The `loadTexture` and `draw` have exact same body regardless of the enemy type, but they use the static field that is different in each one. Is there a way to define something like an uniform method, that when called in derived class would use the field from the derived, not the base?

Thank You for any answers.

Comment: Create a virtual method, `TextureClass *getTexture()`, which all subclasses implement to retrieve their texture pointer, and the common methods use to fetch the texture pointer.

Comment: You could do this with a [CRTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) if it is mandatory the method be static. Otherwise, a non-static virtual method would be preferred.

Comment: @mah by 'common method' do you mean 'global function'?

Comment: @tomi.lee.jones no, I mean `loadTexture` and `draw`, which you said are the same for all subclasses (making them common).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As mentioned by BЈовић, if you want to use inheritance to have the loadTexture() and draw() methods reference the right Texture for your class, the answer probably lies in using [CRTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) to implement your Enemy class, like follows:

```
template<typename TDerivedEnemy>
class Enemy
{
    int hp;
    int damage;
    //
    // all other fields
    //
    static TextureClass* texture; //needs to be static because every instance
                                  //of enemy uses the same texture
public:
    static void loadTexture()
    {
        CreateTextureFromFile("somefilepath",&texture); //needs to be static
      // because textures are loaded before any instance is crated
    }
    void draw()
    {
        DrawToScreen(&texture, ...many data members passed here...);
    }
};
```

Once that is done, you can declare your concrete enemy classes like follows:

```
class EnemyA : public Enemy<EnemyA>
{
public:
    typedef Enemy<EnemyA> tBase;
    ...
};

class EnemyB : public Enemy<EnemyB>
{
public:
    typedef Enemy<EnemyB> tBase;
    ...
};
```

then, in your implementation file, you also need to define the static variables for both EnemyA and EnemyB:

```
TextureClass* EnemyA::tBase::texture = nullptr;
TextureClass* EnemyB::tBase::texture = nullptr;
```

The name "Curiously Recurring Template Pattern" comes from the fact that EnemyA and EnemyB inherit from a template class where they already are parameter templates, hence recursion.

Edit: as discussed in the comment, this approach leads to EnemyA and EnemyB having no common base class, which makes it impossible to refer to them in a uniform way, i.e. you can't declare for instance a

```
std::vector< EnemyA* OR EnemyB* ??? > enemies;
```

because there simply isn't a common base class.
To get around this, you can declare a common abstract base class like follows:

```
class EnemyBase {
public:
    virtual void draw() = 0;
}
```

then make your template implementation inherit from it:

```
template<typename TDerivedEnemy>
class Enemy : public EnemyBase
{
    ...
};
```

Which allows you to do this:

```
std::vector<EnemyBase*> enemies;

//fill the enemies vector
...

for (auto enemy : enemies)
{
    enemy->draw();
}
```

Comment: So now, calling 'objectOfEnemyA.Draw()' will use the texture from the subclass, not the base, even if i dont define it in 'enemyA'? Also, how do i deal with the static 'load texture'? I cant call 'EnemyA::loadTexture()', right? Isnt better to create a Global function that takes a texture adress and loads it?

Comment: You don't need to define the texture in the EnemyA class, since it's already defined in EnemyA's base class: Enemy<EnemyA>. Most compilers should allow you to call EnemyA::loadTexture(...) directly, but on some older compilers, you may need to call EnemyA::tBase::loadTexture(...) instead. One of the points of CRTP, which makes it useful to create for instance singleton base template classes, is that it allows you to effectively "inherit static stuff" by making the template instantiation process create the static elements for you.

Comment: Ah, i think i understand it now: classes derived this way wont share same texture because they dont derive from 'Enemy' but...'Enemy<Derived>', yes? So in fact its kind of like they dont derive from the same 'Enemy'?

Comment: Yes, that's it. Note that this raises an issue: you can't refer to enemies through polymorphism because there is no common base class they derive from. You can get around it by defining such a base class, and making the Enemy class template inherit from it. This base class would in your case probably declare  virtual void draw() = 0;  as an abstract method. Then you could do something like  std::vector<EnemyBase*> enemies;  ...;  for (auto enemy: enemies) enemy->draw(); Editing answer to add this.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways :

1. make EnemyX a template, that has a static texture variable. You can even use [CRTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) for this
2. pass the texture object into the enemy objects (some kind of [IOC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control)) - either to constructor or a method. In this case, the texture would not be static, but it would point to the texture object (pointer or a reference)